# pandas stack second column below first and vice versa

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns and I would like to stack the second column below the first and the first below the second.

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})

   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Desired output:

```
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  1 
4  5  2
5  6  3
```

So far I have tried:

```
pd.concat([df, df[['B','A']].rename(columns={'A':'B', 'B':'A'})])

   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  1
4  5  2
5  6  3
```

Is this the cleanest way?

Comment: Whats wrong with concat. Its neat

Comment: You tell me! I'm not a pandas expert so I am asking :)

Comment: Yep, looks good to me

Comment: @Imran I wonder why you are not satisfied with what you have. Well here cleanliness depends on the number of columns you have. If you have 100 columns, then the suggested solution below is one of the clean ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concat is better if you ask me. But if you have a 100 columns renaming is a pain. As a generalized approach here's one with `numpy flip` and `vstack` i.e

```
v = df.values
pd.DataFrame(pd.np.vstack((v, pd.np.fliplr(v))), columns=df.columns)

   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  1
4  5  2
5  6  3
```

Comment: Use `fliplr` to flip from left to right, and create a 2D array just once (doing it twice is inefficient).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ we are just accessing the data with df.values right? Am I wrong to think array is not being created but just accessed?

Comment: It depends I think. In some cases, a view is returned, and in others, it's a fresh array. Better be safe I suppose.